# Random time between 0 and 20 sec?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, random

How can I create some random time, like 10 seconds.

So when I click the button I have to wait 10 seconds to see the new button?

My question is how to create that random time? And it has to be in Xaml

My code:

```
public void randomButton()
{            
    newBtn.Content = "A New Button";
    Random myRandom = new Random();
    int rand1 = myRandom.Next(0, 400);
    int rand2 = myRandom.Next(0, 400);
    panelButton.Children.Add(newBtn);

    Canvas.SetLeft(newBtn, rand1);
    Canvas.SetTop(newBtn, rand2);

    iRandom = row.Next(-350, 350);
    newBtn.Click += newBtn_Click;
    newBtn.Margin = new Thickness(iRandom, iRandom, 0, 0);
}

private void newBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // here i want the random time to happen!*
    iRandom = row.Next(-350, 350);
    newBtn.Margin = new Thickness(iRandom, iRandom, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private async void newBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // here i want the random time to happen!
    await Task.Delay(5000); // 5 sec, make it random

    iRandom = row.Next(-350, 350);
    newBtn.Margin = new Thickness(iRandom, iRandom, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: But how can I give a random time?

Comment: @Xaml - This gives you a random delay between 2000 and 10000 milliseconds:  
  
    `var rnd = new Random();
    var delay = rnd.Next(5000, 10001);`